# SyntaxError when using literal string interpolation or f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, f-string

Trying to read a csv file and print contents:

```
with open('C:\test.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row[0])}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department in {row[2]}.')
```

I received following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\users\XXX\documents\python> python ReadCSV.py
  File "ReadCSV.py", line 12
    print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row[0])}')
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is your Python version? What is the output of `python -V` or `python3 -V`?

Comment: Did you mean `...join(row)`?

Answer (score 1):

Literal String Interpolation or "f-strings" was only introduced in Python3.6.
See: 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

[image: PEP498]

Your code works fine on Python3.6.
If you are not using Python3.6 (and up), you will get a syntax error.

```
$ python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.7
$ python3.6 readcsv.py 
Column names are c, o, l, 1
        1 works in the 2 department in 3.
        4 works in the 5 department in 6.
```

---

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
$ python3 readcsv.py 
  File "readcsv.py", line 9
    print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row[0])}')
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
$ python readcsv.py 
  File "readcsv.py", line 9
    print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row[0])}')
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```